# net core asp with automatic create and update data field

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a problem with EF and MVC on net core.

I have an "item" model. This model has the required "createdate" and "updateDate" fields (I can't have a record without having the record date).

I use both fields with inheritance over BaseEntity.

The point is that to assign these dates, I do it directly in the context, overriding the "SaveChanges" function.

Because of this, by not giving it a value in either the view or the controller, the model evaluation fails because the dates are null. I actually give it value but after passing validation.

What do you think would be the most correct solution?

This is my model:

```
  public class ItemType : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public int SizeTypeId { get; set; }
    public SizeType SizeType { get; set; }

}
 public class BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeleteDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

this is my savechanges override:

```
 public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var entries = ChangeTracker
            .Entries()
            .Where(e => e.Entity is BaseEntity && (
                    e.State == EntityState.Added
                    || e.State == EntityState.Modified));

        foreach (var entityEntry in entries)
        {
            ((BaseEntity)entityEntry.Entity).UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;

            if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                ((BaseEntity)entityEntry.Entity).CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

this is my controller:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Description,Active,DeleteDate,CreatedDate,UpdatedDate,Comments")] SizeType sizeType)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(sizeType);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(sizeType);
    }
```

Thanks you very much!!

Comment: can you add  [NotMapped] from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations  namespace to those properties?

Comment: if I use  [NotMapped], then .net do not create this fields in by database when I do a migration. I can't do this.

Comment: Separate Model from DTO. It is bad practice to use Model Entities in requests.

Comment: how can I do this? I always use directly Model. Have you some documentation or example? thanks

Answer (score 0):

One easy option would be to just make the properties nullable i.e. `DateTime? CreatedDate` since the entity isn't already created or deleted it makes sense for the CreatedDate or UpdatedDate properties to be null. However, a better option is to just create a DTO or in other words, a ViewModel that wraps the data of your entity and exposes it to the View. For example:

```
public class ItemTypeRequest : BaseEntityRequest
{

   [Required]
   public string Description { get; set; }

   public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

   public int SizeTypeId { get; set; }

   public SizeType SizeType { get; set; }

}

public class BaseEntityRequest
{
   [Required]
   public bool Active { get; set; }

   public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Normally in a well-defined ViewModel, you are exposing to the View only the minimal set of data that is needed to perform the operation. In this case the Create View does not need an Id, CreatedDate, or UpdatedDate, because the entity isn't already created i.e. it does not exist in the database and therefore has no Id or creation date. After creating the ViewModels you can leverage [AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html) to map the ViewModels data to the entity data

```
 var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
     cfg.CreateMap<ItemTypeRequest , ItemType>();
     cfg.CreateMap<ItemType, ItemTypeResponse>();
 });

 var mapper = config.CreateMapper();


 public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ItemTypeRequest itemTypeRequest)
 {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ItemType itemType = mapper.Map<ItemType>(itemTypeRequest);
        _context.Add(itemType);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View();
 }
```

Following the same login, you should create a response DTO/ViewMode this time with more data if you need it i.e.

```
 public class ItemTypeResponse : BaseEntityResponse
 {
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public string Description { get; set; }

  public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

  public int SizeTypeId { get; set; }

  public SizeType SizeType { get; set; }

}

public class BaseEntityResponse
{
   public bool Active { get; set; }

   public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

   public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }

   public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

This time the properties `CreatedDate` and `UpdatedDate` are included since they have values after you have created the entity.